# How should I code to: select checkbox -> table hide in 1sec -> console.log(hide) -> select checkbox again -> show the table -> console.log(show);?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle, hide, show

Unfortunately it doesn't work. (Rather, it works, but not in a proper way.)

**HTML:**

```
  <div>
       <label id="myButton"> Show/Hide
            <input type="checkbox"  name="tableShowOrHide" value="C">
       </label>
  </div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    $('table').finish().show(1000, function () {
        console.log("We can see the table.");
    });
    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        $('table').finish().hide(1000, function () {
            console.log("Was there a table?!");
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have two functions that will run when you click your button. To solve this, combine them in a way like this:

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
if ($("p").is(":visible")) {
    $('table').finish().hide(1000);
    console.log("Was there a table?!");
} else {
    $('table').finish().show(1000);
    console.log("We can see the table.");
}

})
```

If it doesn't work, can you please post the full HTML as well?

Comment: Only the half of it works: originally, the checkbox is unchecked. When I check the checkbox, then the table hides away, it is OK. But when I uncheck the checkbox again, nothing happens.
What kind of "p" did you think of in the 2. line?

Comment: It's too long... Should I paste it in more part in comments or how can I shorten that, in a way you understand the point? (I'm a beginner here as well, sorry)

Comment: The full html is the following:
``` 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WEB2/2.rv.</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jq.css">

</head>
```

Comment: ```
<body>
        <div class="content">
        <div class="">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <br>
                Quas, eligendi fuga corrupti ea quasi sapiente
                sint minima est temporibus dolore autem, atque tenetur!</h2>


            <p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Consectetur porro culpa
                voluptatum quam fugit a obcaecati, magni totam animi iusto
                quisquam quis enim hic repellendus esse ea maiores, vero officiis.</p>
```

Comment: ```
            <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
                Placeat, est nulla quasi suscipit autem facilis eius modi repellat
                sit consectetur, fuga expedita sunt temporibus sint reiciendis
                sapiente impedit eos quibusdam.</p>

            <button class="makeItHappier" onclick="">Tegyük vidámabbá!</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
```

Comment: ```
<div class="scndf">
            <select class="form-select col-6" id="quantiti" onclick="ifSelectedLetHeadChange()">
            </select>

<br> <br><br>
            <table class="col-12 C">
                <thead>
                    <!-- Itt csak azért tettem egymás mellé a th-kat és a td-ket,
                    hogy annyival is kevesebb sorból álljon és így olvashatóbb legyen a kód. -->
                    <tr>
                        <th> lkjél </th> <th> lkjél </th> <th> lkjél </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

Comment: ```                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>dfafda</td> <td>dfafda</td> <td>dfafda</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

<!-- And there are 5 more rows like this in the table -->

            </table>
        </div>
 <div>
            <label id="myButton"> Show/Hide
                <input type="checkbox"  name="tableShowOrHide" value="C">
            </label>

        </div>

<!-- At the end there are the jquery, etc. links and the last is my own js file. -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed "p" to "table" and it works now, thank you! :)

Comment: @TündeT.T. For sake of completeness, please insert the full html into the original question by editing your post.